# Pen tool in Photoshop not becoming larger

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, pen-tool, art

How do i create a larger or smaller stroke using the pen tool in adobe photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the stroke weight in the control bar....

[image]